# How to get the full URL for a request in Hapi

Tags: url, hapi.js

In my hapijs app, given a [`Request` object](http://hapijs.com/api#request-object), how can I find the original, unparsed, unmodified URL?

```js
function getRequestUrl (request) {
    return ...; // What goes here?
}
```

I've found that I can piece it together somewhat from `Request.info.host`, `Request.path`, and `Request.query`, but it lacks the scheme (ie, http vs https), and is a bit of a kludge.  Isn't the plain URL available somewhere?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The full URL isn't stored somewhere you can get it. You need to build it yourself from the parts:

`const url = request.connection.info.protocol 
    + '://' 
    + request.info.host 
    + request.url.path`;

Even though it might seem kludgey, it makes sense if you think about it because *there is no original, unparsed, unmodified URL*. The HTTP request that goes over the wire doesn't contain the URL as typed into the browser address bar for instance:

```
GET /hello?a=1&b=2 HTTP/1.1      // request.url.path
Host: localhost:4000             // request.info.host
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
...
```

And you only know the protocol based on whether the hapi server connection is in TLS mode or not (`request.connection.info.protocol`).

**Things to be aware of**

If you check either:

`request.connection.info.uri` or `request.server.info.uri`

the reported hostname will be the hostname of the actual machine that the server is running on (the output of `hostname` on *nix). If you want the actual host the person typed in the browser (which might be different) you need to check `request.info.host` which is parsed from the HTTP request's Host header)

**Proxies and X-Forwarded-Proto header**

If your request got passed through a proxy(ies)/load balancers/HTTPS terminators, it's possible somewhere along the line HTTPS traffic got terminated and was sent to your server on an HTTP connection, in this case you'll want use the value of the `x-forwarded-proto` header if it's there:

`const url = (request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || request.connection.info.protocol) 
    + '://' 
    + request.info.host 
    + request.url.path`;

With template strings:

```
const url = `${request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || request.connection.info.protocol}://${request.info.host}${request.url.path}`;
```

Comment: `request.connection.info.protocol` is not so good solution. If you need to get the protocol better use `request.headers['x-forwarded-proto']`

Comment: @Petroff thanks, updated my answer with a note about proxies.

Comment: @MattHarrison `request.info.host` gives me localhost instead of domain name but getting it in `'x-forwarded-server': 'my-domain-com'` can you explain why?

Comment: Doesn't work with the latest `hapi` version. But `hapi-url` does, see rigon's answer.

Answer (score 3):

[hapi-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-url) solves this exact problem. It is prepared to work with X-Forwarded headers to run behind a proxy. There is also an option to override the automatic resolution if the library is not able to resolve the URL correctly.

Comment: Nice work.  A couple of suggestions: 1. When you override the `resolve` prototype method, make it unenumerable via `Object.defineProperty`.  2. Add a null check to `HapiUrl.init`.  You already do type checking, but since `typeof null === "object"`, you will get a runtime error if you ever call `HapiUrl.init(null)`.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean by "make it unenumerable". Can you give more details? I created an issue on GitHub to discuss this: https://github.com/rigon/hapi-url/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

I use the following syntax now (using coffee script):

```
server.on 'response', (data) ->
  raw = data.raw.req
  url = "#{data.connection.info.protocol}://#{raw.headers.host}#{raw.url}"
  console.log "Access to #{url}"
```

Or as javascript:

```
​server.on('response', function(data) {
  var raw = data.raw.req;
  var url = data.connection.info.protocol + "://" + 
  raw.headers.host + raw.url;
  console.log("Access to " + url);
});
```

That gives you the exact URL like the user requested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the URL. You have to generate it. I'm using this one:

```
const url = request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] + '://' +
            request.headers.host + 
            request.url.path;
```

Answer (score 0):

nowadays there is simply `request.url`:

https://hapi.dev/api?v=20.2.0#-requesturl