# How to get the full url in Hapi.Js?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

`request.url` is an object which returns the route but not the full url in node/hapi framework.

How can I get the full url?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840286/how-to-get-the-full-url-for-a-request-in-hapi/31841704#31841704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://hapijs.com/api):

> url - the parsed request URI.

So, the URL object, in fact, is only an URI (that doesn't contains the protocol info and host).

For a full URL, you need to build it as the following:

```
var url = request.connection.info.protocol + '://' + request.info.host + request.url.path;
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer myself:

```
request.info.host
```